# Upload file with SCP bash script

Tags: bash, ssh

I need bash script to upload file with SCP. How I can do that in script, I want to call that script fromother program. ( I know to do that with EXPECT but I need plain bash script). Can anybody help ?

Comment: Please don't [cross-post](http://superuser.com/questions/248358/upload-file-with-scp-bash-script).

Answer (score 3):

I strongly recommend setting up [key-based authentication](http://pkeck.myweb.uga.edu/ssh/) for your system. Then you could use [ssh-agent](http://mah.everybody.org/docs/ssh) to automate unlocking the key for your program.

Answer (score 1):

> **I need bash script to upload file with SCP**

Well then just type the `scp` command in the file and make it executable.

If you're asking how to avoid being prompted for password, I strongly recommend you to use SSH-keys. [Here](http://pkeck.myweb.uga.edu/ssh/) is a really simple tutorial on how to set it up properly.